# Maximum node splits in B-tree in terms of insertions and branching order

Tags: b-tree

Is there any algorithm to calculate maximum number of node splits that can occur in given number of insertions and highest branching order? Lets say I want to insert 10 elements to an empty B-tree with highest branching order of 3. Is there way to calculate the maximum number of splits that will occur?

Comment: I believe points for possible algorithm can be as explained in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/103522/49261) question. I want to know if closed formula is possible.